# A Pattern/Sequence formula

Tags: design-patterns, sequences

If you have this pattern 5, 7, 12, 20, 31, 45, and those are the outputs of a function where F(0) = 5, and F(1) = 7 and so on, what is the function? I figured out that the differences between the numbers in the sequence progress in increments of 3 so I came up with (3x+2) but I'm not quite sure how to combine that with the rest of the data to make a function that fits the data. This is a math problem, but it is an exercise for my computer logic class.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You were close to the right track.

d/dx = 3x + b

F(x) = (3/2)x<sup>2</sup> + bx + c

Plugging in values gives 1/2 for b and 5 for c

So:

```
F(x) = (3/2)x^2 + (1/2)x + 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I appreciate the help, but would you mind explaining how you arrived at that answer? I'm trying to figure out if there's a series of logical steps I can take to solve more problems like this more efficiently

Comment: I used calculus. The change of the change is 3. Integrating that gives d/dx, or 3x + b. Integrating again gives f(x) which is (3/2)x^2 + bx + c. Plugging in known values for (x, f(x)) (0, 5), (1, 7), (2, 12) allows us to solve for b and c

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, really cleared things up. I'm not sure whether I'm supposed to ask another question here in the comments, but what if the change in the pattern is exponential. I have 0, 2, 6, 14, 30, 62, and 126. Does the same method you used to solve the last sequence formula apply as well? I know that the difference in the terms rises at a rate of 2^n where n is the nth term, but I'm not sure how integrating that will get me any closer to the formula I need. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hm, no, I don't think integrating that one will help. That one I would line up next to 2^x and I noticed that it was 2 off, or 2^x - 2